# Array search code

Tags: java, arrays, search

In the book 'Data structures and algorithms in java' the following Array search method code is provided:

```
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j< nElems; j++)            // for each element,
        if( a[j].getLast().equals(searchName))  // found item?
             break;                       // exit loop before end
    if(j == nElems)                    // gone to end?
      return null;                    // yes, can't find it
    else
      return a[j];                    // no, found it
}
```

I am trying to understand why there needs to be a if(j == nElems) check? Wouldn't the method work the same if it were written as:

```
{           
    int j;
    for(j=0; j <nElems; j++)               
      if( a[j].getLast().equals(searchName))      
         return a[j];              
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You could understand the code better if format it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would :P You could declare the `j` inside the for to limit its scope as well.

In the first implementation what it do is check if it iterated over all elements and didn't find anything, because `j` was incremented until it is equal the the condition of stop of the `for-loop`. I.e., it didn't stop because of `break`, indicating that it found an element.

I prefer your solution because it's easier to read :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of these ways are give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Well ,  **j** never equals to nElems   so this condition `(j==nElems)` is not wrong BUT  it's not Working .
You can make it like this  `(j==nElems-1)`   but it's steal waste of code , So your  algorithm is better than the first one .